# Jest doesn't seem to understand "import type"

Tags: angular, typescript, jestjs, type-only-import-export

We recently updated our monorepository to:

- Nx 14.3.6
- Angular 14.0.3
- Jest 28.1.1
- TypeScript 4.7.4

After the upgrade the compilation succeeded, but at runtime we got lots of errors like "***emitDecoratorMetadata causes runtime errors by referencing type-only imports with namespaces***"
(https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42624). This error was also reported by ESLint.

We solved this by (for all types and interfaces) replacing all "**import**" statements to "**import type**" statements. This fixed the runtime errors and the application worked again.
To fix the ESLint error we also had to install and use the "eslint-plugin-import" extension.

So far so good, but now our tests stopped working. **It seems that Jest doesn't understand the "import type" statement.**
In every unit test of a class that uses "import type", the tests fail with this error:

> ReferenceError: Zyz is not defined

(where xyz is an imported type in the tested class, e.g.

```
// some-component.ts
import type { Xyz } from '...';
...
```

If we remove the "type" from the "import type" statement the test works but then the runtime errors reoccur.

I've searched quite a bit already (mostly by trying to use/reconfigure babel, because I found this post: https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10981) but for now I'm unable to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be fixed by the workaround explained here:
https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1199#issuecomment-1168802943

So in tsconfig.spec.json configure the "include" property to contain all typescript files:

```
// tsconfig.spec.json
{
  ...
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Previously we had:

```
// tsconfig.spec.json
{
  ...
  "include": ["**/*.spec.ts", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.d.ts", "jest.config.ts"]
}
```

**Edit:**
In addition to the above configuration it seems that **ts-jest** also requires non-isolatedModules.
We were using **isolatedModules**: true, but it caused the same problem with type-only imports.

If anyone knows why or has a better idea: please let me know.

Comment: No luck sadly...