# Can't run unit tests when using type-only imports

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-library, jest-preset-angular, type-only-import-export

[Follow up on this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67539780/one-or-more-import-cycles-would-need-to-be-created-to-compile-this-component-wh/75994725#75994725)

I've build a library with a component and a directive, which normally causes an import cycle.

Component

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-resizable',
  templateUrl: `<div [resizableGlyph]="['top', 'start']"></div>`,
  providers: [
    { provide: 'RESIZABLE', useExisting: ResizableComponent }
  ]
})
export class ResizableComponent {}
```

Directive

```
import { Directive, Inject, Input } from '@angular/core';
// import { ResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component'; // Project won't build (npm run build -- --configuration production)
import type { ResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component'; // Unit tests don't work
export type Position = 'top' | 'end' | 'bottom' | 'start';

@Directive({ selector: '[resizableGlyph]' })
export class ResizableGlyphDirective {
  constructor(@Inject('RESIZABLE') private resizable: ResizableComponent) { }
  @Input('resizableGlyph') positions: Position[] = [];
}
```

To solve this we need to use the `import type` annotation. However this breaks the unit tests (jest):

> ReferenceError: ResizableComponent is not defined

I've already checked and tried all comments in the following links:

- [[Github] [Bug] type-only imports cause ReferenceError](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/issues/1199)

  - Change tsconfig includes
  - Use `jest-preset-angular` 13.0.1
  - `"emitDecoratorMetadata": false`
- [Jest doesn't seem to understand "import type"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72771723/jest-doesnt-seem-to-understand-import-type)

[Here's a minimal reproduction](https://github.com/PieterjanDeClippel/angular-library-import-cycles). Did anyone manage to use **type-only imports** and get the unit-tests to work?

References:

- [Add jest to angular workspace](https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/main/README.md)
- [Angular NG3003](https://angular.io/errors/NG3003)
- [Type-only imports/exports](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-8.html#type-only-imports-and-export)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is caused when using typed DI in the constructor:

```
import type { BsResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component';

...

constructor(@Inject(RESIZABLE) private resizable: BsResizableComponent) {
}
```

becomes

```js
import type { BsResizableComponent } from '../resizable/resizable.component';

...

// Can't use typed DI because of the `import type`
private readonly resizable: BsResizableComponent;
constructor(@Inject(RESIZABLE) resizable: any) {
  this.resizable = resizable;
}
```

And the problem is solved